# Catch an error in case of bad XML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-3.2

I am using `xml.dom.minidom` for parsing some XML from a string. I need to handle an error case when the supplied XML is malformed. What error do I catch?

In other words, what should replace `BadXml` below?

```
try:
    from xml.dom import minidom
    in_xml = minidom.parseString(some_string)
except BadXml:
    handle_bad_xml(some_string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the only answer is that you must catch `Exception`.  `minidom` does not implement `DOMException`, and while it does use some general exceptions from `xml.dom`, it also freely uses `TypeError` and other standard python exceptions whose only single common base is `Exception` itself.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Realistically if you need something more specific, then `minidom` isn't for you - this is part of the "super-lightweight" leanness of `minidom`.  If you need features that doesn't provide you might want to look at `lxml`, `ElementTree`, or any of the other DOM providers available.

Comment: Okay. I will stick to minidom for the time being, and switch if I feel the need. I am accepting your post as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want:

```
from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError

try:
    from xml.dom import minidom
    in_xml = minidom.parseString(some_string)
except ExpatError:
    handle_bad_xml(some_string)
```

Comment: I tried a malformed string and that is what it raised. But does it always raise that same exception? What does the choice of parser depend upon?

Comment: `minidom` raises many exceptions directly which do not inherit from `ExpatError` (and indeed there's no guarantee that the default parser will continue to be `expatbuilder` in a given version of python)

Comment: `minidom` does raise other exceptions, but in the case of malformed XML (and the current use of `expat`) I *think* it always raises `ExpatError` as it's a parse error. I need to dig into source to confirm that.